# bootstrap dropdown in svg with d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, bootstrap-4

I want to draw a graph (not a tree because some nodes can have multiple parents). Each node of the graph, when clicked, should display a dropdown menu with a list of text. I am new to d3.js but I have seen examples of bootstrap dropdowns. Thus, I tried to draw the nodes inside svg with the help of the ***foreignObject*** tag. I still do not see any dropdowns with the following implementation:

```js
// call the main function
main();

function getGraphData(){
    var graph =   {
         "nodes":
         [
           {id: "abc", summary: "summary of abc", menuitems: [{id: "abc1"}, {id: "abc2"}],
            "x_": 0.1, "y_": 0.5
           },
           {id: "xyz", summary: "summary of xyz", menuitems: [{id: "xyz1"}],
           "x_": 0.3, "y_": 0.1
           },
           {id: "bcd", summary: "summary of bcd", menuitems: [{id: "bcd1"}, {id: "bcd22"}, {id: "bcd3"}],
           "x_": 0.3, "y_": 0.6
           },
           {id: "cde", summary: "summary of cde", menuitems: [{id: "cde1"}, {id: "cde2"}],
           "x_": 0.5, "y_": 0.5
           },
         ],
         "links":
         [
           {source: 0, target: 1},
           {source: 1, target: 2},
           {source: 0, target: 3},
           {source: 0, target: 2},
         ]
       };


  return graph;
}

function main(){
  var graph = getGraphData();
  drawGraphForeignObjects(graph);
}

function drawGraphForeignObjects(data){
  var nodes = data.nodes;
  var edges = data.links;

  var svg = d3.select('svg');
  var width = svg.attr("width");
  var height = svg.attr("height");

  svg.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

  console.log(svg.size());

  var foreign = svg.selectAll('foreignObject')
    .data(nodes);

  var rectH = 40;
  var rectW = 80;
  var rectRound = 5;

  var newForeign = foreign.enter().append("foreignObject")
    .attr('class', "node")
    .attr("requiredExtensions", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .attr('x', function (d){ return d.x_ * width; })
    .attr('y', function (d){ return d.y_ * height; })
    .attr("rx", rectRound)
    .attr("ry", rectRound)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("width", rectW)


  var dropdown_div = newForeign.append('xhtml:div')
    
    .attr("class", "dropdown")

  dropdown_div.append('xhtml:button')
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .attr("class", "btn btn-success dropdown-toggle")
    .attr("type", "button")
    .attr("data-toggle", "dropdown")
    .attr("aria-haspopup", "true")
    .attr("aria-expand", "false")
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
    .attr("id", function (d) { return "dropdown" + d.id; })

  var dropdown_menu = dropdown_div.append('xhtml:div')
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .attr("class", "dropdown-menu")
    .style("background-color", "blue")

  dropdown_menu.append('xhtml:a')
    .attr("class", "dropdown-item")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .text("Hello")
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: in Chrome I had to remove the `requiredExtensions` attribute to render the dropdowns.

Answer (score 3):

While debugging your code, I found that `foreign` is undefined in Chrome and IE browser. Your code shows drop-downs in Firefox. After doing some research, found that

> Chrome doesn't create the SVG foreignObject elements properly - they
>   appear in the DOM as foreignobject and can't then be selected by
>   d3.selectAll('foreignObject') (nor d3.selectAll('foreignobject')
>   because D3 knows about the proper names of things in the SVG XML
>   namespace). Solution: use a class to identify all <foreignObject>s.

http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411